# Как правильно привязать ObservableCollection<CustomType> к ListView .NET MAUI?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, maui, winui3

Это всего лишь отслеживаемая коллекция пар `Key + Value`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class="MauiApp1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Name="This"
    Title="Test MainPage"
    BindingContext="{x:Reference This}">
    <ScrollView Margin="20">
        <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Binding Vars}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell.View>
                            <VerticalStackLayout>
                                <Label Text="{x:Binding Key}" />
                                <Label Text="{x:Binding Value}" FontSize="12" />
                            </VerticalStackLayout>
                        </ViewCell.View>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

```cs
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
namespace MauiApp1;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Vars { get; } = new();
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        System.Collections.IDictionary dict = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables();
        foreach (var oKey in dict.Keys)
        {
            if (oKey is not string key || dict[key] is not string value) continue;
            Vars.Add(KeyValuePair.Create(key, value));
        }
    }
}
```

Визуально этот код работает, IntelliSense так же дает правильные подсказки, но после вывода логов обнаружил неприятные сообщения:

```
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Diagnostics.BindingDiagnostics: Warning: 'Key' property not found on 'MauiApp1.MainPage', target property: 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Label.Text'
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Diagnostics.BindingDiagnostics: Warning: 'Value' property not found on 'MauiApp1.MainPage', target property: 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Label.Text'
```

Если кратко: свойств `Key и Value` нет в`MainPage`. Почему в `MainPage`? ... , ведь поиск контекста должен остановиться на `ListView ItemsSource`.

Можно ли это как то исправить и не видеть таких ошибок?

PS: Пробовал использовать нестандартный кастомный объект с `INotifyCollectionChanged`, результат то же.

**PPS(update)**: Вероятно, немного не точно описал проблему, `KeyValuePair` здесь только для примера, в приложении используется `класс:INotifyPropertyChanged`, но результат то же.

Использование `xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:***" + <DataTemplate x:DataType="vm:KeyValue">` со своим объектом тоже не помогает.

Само приложение компилируется и работает, но в логи постоянно выпадает целая куча предупреждений о привязках(не при компиляции, а именно в работающем приложении). Например с тем же кодом(только привязка `x:Bind`) в варианте `WinUI_3` нет ни одной ошибки или предупреждения, а [судя по этой картинке](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/what-is-maui#how-net-maui-works) `MAUI` это и есть `WinUI_3` для `Windows`:

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Vars}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" />
                <TextBlock FontSize="12" Text="{Binding Value}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Попробуйте убрать в биндинге пространство имён "x"

Comment: @Nikolay Пробовал, не помогает, причем это только с `.NET MAUI`, с остальными платформами все в порядке.

Answer (score 1):

Это не решение вопроса, но что было обнаружено: вероятно, с `ListView` какие-то проблемы.

Если в коде выше заменить `ListView` на идентичный, и как описывает документация более гибкий [CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/) ошибки странным образом пропадают:

```xml
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Vars}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="{Binding Key}" />
                <Label FontSize="12" Text="{Binding Value}" />
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```